# Fade out, replace html and fade in randomly

Tags: jquery

I created effect for my online user images but  I have some problems with this script. I have 9 images. 3 images are hidden. When one random image fade out i want to replace it with one of hidden images. I don't want to see same images in first 6 images.

http://seninsayfan.net/user.html

```
$(document).ready(function() {
setInterval(function() {
 var pic = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
  var picture = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
$(".image-" + pic).each(function() {
$(this).fadeOut(500, function() {
     $(this).html($(".image-" + picture).html());
    });
$(this).fadeIn(500);
});
}, 1000);
});
```

Thanks All Masters

Comment: mind putting it on http://jsfiddle.net with the html part?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nihal/24Qat/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done some changes in your code, you can see a live example at http://jsfiddle.net/24Qat/22/

I've set an array of images:

```
var images = {};
images[0] = "http://seninsayfan.net/ext/avatar/img1.jpg";
images[1] = "http://seninsayfan.net/ext/avatar/img2.png";
images[2] = "http://seninsayfan.net/ext/avatar/img4.jpg";
images[3] = "http://seninsayfan.net/ext/avatar/image1.jpg";
images[4] = "http://seninsayfan.net/ext/avatar/image2.gif";
images[5] = "http://seninsayfan.net/ext/avatar/pic1.gif";
images[6] = "http://seninsayfan.net/ext/avatar/pic2.jpg";
images[7] = "http://seninsayfan.net/ext/avatar/pic3.jpg";
images[8] = "http://seninsayfan.net/ext/avatar/pic4.gif";
```

and i save the images indexes:

```
var shown = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
var hidden = [6,7,8];
```

Than I use choose a source and a target to make the swap:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        // choose target index
        var old_pic =  Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
        // choose source index
        var new_pic = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
        $(".image-" + old_pic).fadeOut(500, function() {
            $(this).find('img').attr("src", images[hidden[new_pic]]);
            var temp = shown[old_pic];
            shown[old_pic] = hidden[new_pic];
            hidden[new_pic] = temp;
        }).fadeIn(500);
    }, 1000);
});
```

Please note, for leaner code I've changed the indexes to start from 0. As well, I've deleted the last 3 images (need only 6 containers), so the html should be :

```
<div class="image image-0" ><img src="http://seninsayfan.net/ext/avatar/img1.jpg"/></div>
<div class="image image-1" ><img src="http://seninsayfan.net/ext/avatar/img2.png"/></div>
<div class="image image-2" ><img src="http://seninsayfan.net/ext/avatar/img4.jpg"/></div>
<div class="image image-3" ><img src="http://seninsayfan.net/ext/avatar/image1.jpg"/></div>
<div class="image image-4" ><img src="http://seninsayfan.net/ext/avatar/image2.gif"/></div>
<div class="image image-5" ><img src="http://seninsayfan.net/ext/avatar/pic1.gif"/></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you `fadeOut()` an image set it's class or id to 'hidden' or 'fadedOut'. Then when you are trying to `fadeIn()` another one, choose from those hidden or fadedOut, and when you fade them in, clear their class or id 'hidden' or 'fadedOut'.